# Notice: Undefined variable: category_id

Tags: categories

[image]

**Here is my category.php code**

```
<?php
remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_taxonomy_title_description', 15 ); 
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'prettycreative_do_taxonomy_title_description', 15 );

function prettycreative_do_taxonomy_title_description() { 
    global $wp_query; 
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) >= 2 ) { return; } 
    $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); 
    if ( ! $term || ! isset( $term->meta ) ) { return; } 
    $headline = $intro_text = ''; 
    if ($term->meta['headline'] )) { 
        $headline = sprintf( '%s', strip_tags( $term->meta['headline'] ) ); 
    } 
    if ( apply_filters( 'genesis_term_intro_text_output', $term->meta['intro_text']) ) { 
        $intro_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_term_intro_text_output', $term->meta['intro_text'] ); 
    } 
    // if ( $headline || $intro_text ) // printf( '%sDropdown', $headline . $intro_text ); ?>

<div class="archive-description taxonomy-description clearfix">
    <div class="alignleft"><h1><?php $current_category = single_cat_title("", true); ?></h1><?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?> </div>
    <div class="alignright">
        <form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">

            <?php
            $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'Select Category' ),
                // 'show_count'       => 1, // Show the number of Posts
                'orderby'          => 'name', // ID is the default
                'echo'             => 0, // Send output to browser (1/True) or return output to PHP (0/False)
                'child_of'         => $term->term_id, // Display all categories that are descendants (i.e. children & grandchildren) of the category identified by its ID
                'hierarchical'     => 1, // Show child categories indented
                'hide_if_empty'    => 1, // enable if the dropdown should not appear when there are no sub categories
            );
            ?>

            <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
            <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
            <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

            <?php echo $select; ?>

            <noscript>
                <input type="submit" value="View" />
            </noscript>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'prettycreative_body_class' );
/**
 * Adds a css class to the body element
 *
 * @param  array $classes the current body classes
 * @return array $classes modified classes
 */
function prettycreative_body_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'grid-archive';
    return $classes;
}
/**
 * Display as Columns
 *
 */
function be_portfolio_post_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_main_query() ) { // conditional to ensure that column classes do not apply to Featured widgets
        $columns = 4; // Set the number of columns here
        $column_classes = array( '', '', 'one-half', 'one-third', 'one-fourth', 'one-fifth', 'one-sixth' );
        $classes[] = $column_classes[$columns];
        global $wp_query;
        if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post || 0 == $wp_query->current_post % $columns )
            $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'be_portfolio_post_class' );
// Remove post info
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
// Remove the post content (requires HTML5 theme support)
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
// Remove entry meta from entry footer incl. markup
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_close', 15 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );
// Remove the post image (requires HTML5 theme support)
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'prettycreative_featured_image', 7 );
function prettycreative_featured_image() {
    if ( $image = genesis_get_image( 'format=url&size=portfolio' ) ) {
        printf( '<div class="recipe-image"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark"><img src="%s" alt="%s" /></a></div>', get_permalink(), $image, the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) );
    }
}

genesis();`
```

Comment: What is the question? in the scope of the function `prettycreative_do_taxonomy_title_description()` the var `$category_id` hasn't been defined at all

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you want to get the ID of your current category. You need to first get the category using :

**Method 1**

```
$myCategory = get_the_category();
```

And then instead of $category_id` use this:

```
$myCategory[0]->cat_ID;
```

To retrieve the ID. OR:

**Method 2**

`$myCategory = get_queried_object();` to get the category and replace `$category_id` with:

```
$myCategory->term_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all posts that belong to category id:

```
<?php
$myCategory = get_queried_object();

 $category_query_args = array(
     'cat' => $myCategory->term_id
 );

 $category_query = new WP_Query( $category_query_args );
 if($category_query->have_posts()){
     while($category_query->have_posts()):$category_query->the_post();
        the_excerpt();
 endwhile;
 }
?>
```